# Automated test cannot set input due to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, browser-automation

I am writing automation using Ruby built on a framework of Selenium, Watir and Cucumber.  Most recently, one of my tests began to fail due to a change in a text field, specifically, a Javascript call occurs upon interaction with that field that limits the inputs to numeric KeyCodes, with some allowances for decimals, and pasting.  When this change went into effect, inputs that I attempted to enter were no longer accepted with the exception of ".".  I have attempted converting to numerical inputs (to_i and to_f), as well as alternate means of setting the value (see the following):

```
browser.text_field(:id, "rate").set(val)
```

or

```
browser.text_field(:id, "rate").value=(val)
```

or

```
browser.text_field(:id, "rate").send_keys :numpad1
```

In all these cases, nothing appears in the input box except the decimal.  I cannot figure out how to deal with this Javascript.  My question is 1)  Has anyone run across and fixed something similar to this, and barring that 2)  How can I temporarily turn off Javascript programmatically to enter values, then turn it back on so as to be able to retain the integrity of the rest of the environment?

Answer (score 0):

When necessary, fight JavaScript with JavaScript:

`browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('rate').setAttribute('value', '12345')")`